# Alternate file names with a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to know if there is a better way of renaming two files and alternate the names within a batch file. I am currently using this method.

```
ren httpd.conf temp_httpd.conf 
if exist _httpd.conf (
ren _httpd.conf httpd.conf
ren temp_httpd.conf _httpd.conf
)else (
ren _httpd.conf httpd.conf
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the way is ok, but the false-case can't work.
If the file _http.conf doesn't exists, you try to rename it to http.conf.

I would change it to

```
if exist _httpd.conf (
  ren httpd.conf temp_httpd.conf
  ren _httpd.conf httpd.conf
  ren temp_httpd.conf _httpd.conf
)
```

Comment: ...and lastly: `del temp_httpd.conf`?

Comment: @Andriy: the temp__httpd.conf shouldn't exist anymore, it is renamed to _httpd.conf

Comment: Oops, you are right, of course. Can't imagine what I was thinking.

Comment: Ok thanks for your thoughts jeb, I will go with my method because _http.conf dose already exist.